Dependency (upstream) services are undefined with no useful error when doing e2e testing using Jest
This is in NestJs, using Jest. I am trying to test my controller, which relies on my "main" service. I wish to perform e2e testing on the controller. (To clarify, my smaller unit tests of the dependency services are all working fine - no issues there.)
My controller's constructor and first method I am testing look like this:
export class MyController{
constructor(
private aService: AService,
private bService: BService,
//etc etc multiple such services
) {}

@Post('/login')
async login(@Body() logDto: LogDTO)
{
console.log('aService: ' + this.aService);
console.log('bService: ' + this.bService);
//etc etc
//then the code
}
}

I've set up the test as normal, tediously importing everything, mocking repos, etc, and when I missed things, I got an error saying I missed importing some service or so on.
My very first test in the spec.ts is:
//controller, aService, bService, etc were all defined in the beforeEach block
it('should be defined', () => {
expect(controller).toBeDefined();
expect(aService).toBeDefined();
expect(bService).toBeDefined();
//etc
}

This test is passing. Everything is defined fine in my spec.ts. However, the moment I try to run a test involving the actual controller.ts, I get errors like "Cannot read properties of undefined" the moment I try to execute a method from a dependency service. And, those console.logs confirm that the dependency services are all undefined in the actual controller itself.
I tried to ensure that I didn't miss any imports, but without any actually useful error messages, I'm completely stuck. I've never done E2E testing with Jest before, so this is completely new ground for me, too.
EDIT: I should also mention that if I start up my program and hit the exposed APIs with Postman, it is working as expected. So, I'm messing something up with the tests itself.

Does MyController have the @Controller() decorator?

Yes, it does! And MyController is present in the controllers array of the beforeEach block in the spec.ts, as well.

Usually if you're getting undefined in the dependencies, then either the metadata is not being set correctly by the transpilation process (ts-jest most likely, unless you're using something else) or there's a circular file import that's causing the dependency to be called undedfined and Nest isn't quite catching it for some reason
